# celery: how to refresh scheduled task list after revoking?

Tags: redis, scheduled-tasks, celery

I revoked all task using below code.

```
from celery.task.control import inspect
from celery.task.control import revoke

i = inspect()
queues = i.scheduled()
keys = queues.keys()
all_tasks = []
tasks = []
if len(keys) > 0:
    print keys[0]
    all_tasks = queues[keys[0]]

for task in all_tasks:
    revoke(task['request']['id'], terminate=True)
```

but inspect().scheduled() returns same tasks berfore i revoke all. 
How can I get task list except revoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every async_result object has `status` property which shows the status of the task. So you can do this if you have a list of `all_tasks`.

```
unrevoked_tasks = []
for task in all_tasks:
    if task.status != 'REVOKED':
        unrevoked_tasks += task
```

or better use a list comprehension like this

```
unrevoked_tasks = [task for task in all_tasks if task.status != 'REVOKED']
```